# Rotated array modifier around constant origin?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to use an array modifier with a rotated empty to expand and contract six sectors of a circle. When I move the actual mesh, I want the five copies to move directly away from the origin. However, when I move the actual wedge, the copies are offset by the position of the empty, not just the rotation, so they don't move directly away from the origin. The second, expanded, picture is how I want it to look, but for the picture I had to move the wedge, then set its origin back to the center. Is there an easy way to do this without changing the origin each time?

Contracted:
[image: Contracted]
Expanded:
[image: Expanded]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use an array modifier, animate motion for local axis instead.

Make only one pie slice, you can place the object center wherever you like, but at the circle center will make things easier, making sure the one of the slice's local axis is aligned with the desired motion vector.

Clone duplicate the object into six instances so that they have proper rotation 60º apart.

Then all you have to do is select all slices and move them along the local axis by double tapping the desired direction like <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd> in my case. All will move apart from the center.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Copy Location modifier to the Empty, from Word Space to Local Space.

[image: copy location]

Notice that this will create a dependency cycle that will result in a delay in the updates.

[image: dependency cycle delay]